# Cannot find parameter in DELETE endpoint in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cannot access the supplied url param in my delete endpoint and i have no idea why. GET, POST and PUT works just fine.

```
const express  = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const courses = [
    {id: 1, name: 'course1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'course2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'course3'},
];

app.delete('/api/courses/:id', (res, req) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

I do a DELETE in Postman supplying the url "localhost:5000/api/courses/1" and i get the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;id&#39; of undefined
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at app.delete (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\index.js:84:28)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Ove\WebstormProjects\Vidley\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone please explain to me what is going on here? Only the DELETE endpoint acts like this, all others are fine

Comment: Are you sending anything in the body? Try sending an empty object or something. Maybe also try converting it to a `GET` as a sanity check. (I know you said 'only the delete does this' but maybe it's that `:id` thats off. Does that part work with GET?

Comment: if i simply change DELETE to GET and use the same url i get                            {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "course1"
}                                                                                                                                 as returned value. Body is empty in DELETE, and i'm using header "Content-Type": "application/json". If i turn this off, it still doesn't work

Comment: you get a dash? `-`

Comment: dash as returned? No

Comment: Empty object in body still gives the same error

Comment: Tested this on my laptop (different OS) with a fresh postman install, same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express passes your handler `(req, res)`, not `(res, req)`, so your `req` is actually `res` and doesn't have a `.params` field.